# ngx-bootstrap datepicker output format is not ISO format

Tags: datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

The default output format of ngx-bootstrap datepicker is not ISO format as documented.
I would welcome this format but the actual format that I get is:

Sun Aug 02 2020 19:17:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker-anjymv)

I know there are ways to post process the format but this format seems weird for a default output format.  Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vanilla JavaScript there is a '**Date**' object, the default output of which gives you the line you are seeing:

```
Sun Aug 02 2020 19:17:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

In physical memory, your Date object is actually being stored as the number of milliseconds since "**January 1, 1970, 00:00:00**" which using our above line is actually "**1596410220000**" milliseconds.

You can read the full specifications for the '**Date**' object here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates

Meanwhile, **to answer your question more specifically**, your date picker is not giving the output you listed but instead applying its date to a '**Date**' object (**newDate**). You are then setting another '**Date**' object (**updatedDate**) to be equal to the Date object assigned by your date-picker (**newDate**).

This is done here:

```
onValueChange(newDate: Date) {
    this.updatedDate = newDate;
}
```

So in memory your updatedDate is now represented as "**1596410220000**" milliseconds. When you output that '**Date**' object to your HTML your browser is going to use the default output for the '**Date**' object, giving you:

```
Sun Aug 02 2020 19:17:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

So there are two solutions that you can use if you want to get that Date into a different format.

First you can call a method on your newDate to return a different formatted string. For example, if we wanted to output it as the ISO string that you were looking for originally ***we change this***:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  myDateValue: Date;
  updatedDate: Date;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myDateValue = new Date();
  }

  onValueChange(newDate: Date) {
    this.updatedDate = newDate;
  }
```

***To this:***

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  myDateValue: Date;
  updatedDate: String;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myDateValue = new Date();
  }

  onValueChange(newDate: Date) {
    this.updatedDate = newDate.toISOString();
  }
```

First we changed "**updatedDate**" to be a string object and we called the method "**toISOString()**" on our "**newDate**" (which is the Date returned from our date-picker). This gives us the ISO formatted string, which for our example is:

```
2020-08-02T23:17:00.000Z
```

The other option is to simply apply formatting to your date in your angular DatePipe. For example, ***if we change this:***

```
</div>
   Updated Date: {{updatedDate}}
</div>
```

***To this:***

```
</div>
   Updated Date: {{updatedDate | date:"shortTime"}}
</div>
```

We would be applying the shortTime format which is "h:mm a" or for our example:

```
7:17 PM
```

You can read the full list of angular date formats here: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

### To summarize:

Vanilla JavaScript (not angular or ngx-bootstrap) is controlling the output format for the "**Date**" object here. While the output looks weird, the variable itself is not stored in that format but in milliseconds (*UNIX epoch time*). You can call methods on a Date object to get various formats (including ISO, UTC, etc) or you can format from angular by passing a format command along the datepipe.

Comment: Thank you for the rapid response and thank you for the detailed answer.  Everything is clear now.  I very much appreciate the details you provided and the time you spent responding to this.